# Rewrite a function so it works in an older browser

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript function (it is in .jade file though I am fairly sure that doesn't make any difference):

```
    function setStopCommand(path, row)
    {
        if (row.sensor_active == 1)
        {
            var id = row.sensor_id;
            var editSensorId_id = 'edit_sensor_id_' + id;
            var editIpAddress_id = 'edit_ip_address_' + id;
            var controlSelect_id = 'control-select_'+ id;

            var params = 
            {
                [editSensorId_id] : row.sensor_id,
                [editIpAddress_id] : row.sensor_ip,
                [controlSelect_id] : 4
            };
            console.log(JSON.stringify(params));

            post(path, params);
        }
    }
```

This works fine in a modern (latest version of Chrome) browser. The output of the stringify is similar to this (the id can change depending on what is sending the command):

```
{"edit_sensor_id_0C-29-ED-C7-DA":"0C-29-ED-C7-DA","edit_ip_address_0C-29-ED-C7-DA":"192.168.226.131","control-select_0C-29-ED-C7-DA":4}
```

However this doesn't work in a very old version of Chrome that we are using on an embedded device and upgrading Chrome isn't possible.

How can I achieve the same effect but compliant with an older browser? I can't change the output - it is mimicking that the command is coming from an older system.

There is probably an answer on StackOverflow but since I don't know what the name of the technique is I can't search for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problematic bit that older browsers don't support is [computed object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring), Chrome added support for them in version 49.0.
You can easily bypass the issue by using the older syntax:

```
var id = row.sensor_id;
var editSensorId_id = 'edit_sensor_id_' + id;
var editIpAddress_id = 'edit_ip_address_' + id;
var controlSelect_id = 'control-select_' + id;

var params = {};
params[editSensorId_id] = row.sensor_id;
params[editIpAddress_id] = row.sensor_ip;
params[controlSelect_id] = 4;
```